# XSLT performance when searching entire document for Id

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML document with Id's attached to elements, for example:

```
<Section>
    <Field Id="1">... content ...</Field>
    <Field Id="2">... content ...</Field>
    <Section>
        <Field Id="5">... content ...</Field>
        <Field Id="6">... content ...</Field>
        <Section>
            <Field Id="10">... content ...</Field>
            <Field Id="20">... content ...</Field>
        ...
        </Section>
     ...
     </Section>
...
</Section>
```

The actual documents have many nested sections and fields.  Is a search for a particular Id performed using an XPath expression such as:

```
 //Field[@Id=$vSearchId]
```

potentially an expensive operation?  `$vSearchId` here represents a variable  in XSL stylesheet holding the Id search for.

Are there more efficient ways to perform such a lookup, such as building an index?  I looked at `xsl:key` but I wasn't sure how to use it for a search across the entire document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I looked at `xsl:key` but I wasn't sure how to use it for a search
>   across the entire document.

Like this?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="fld" match="Field" use="@Id" />
<xsl:variable name="vSearchId">6</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('fld', $vSearchId)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is it possible to define a function that returns the node matched by the template?

Comment: @dave I am afraid I don't follow.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a key:
`<xsl:key name="id-register" match="Field" use="@Id"/>`

Afterwards you could use this key to process occurrences of `<Field>` with a specific Id:

`<xsl:for-each select="key('id-register','10')">
    <!-- Do Stuff -->
</xsl:for-each>`

Answer (score 1):

Is a search for a particular Id performed using an XPath expression such as:

```
 //Field[@Id=$vSearchId]
```

potentially expensive?

Yes, it is potentially expensive. But only potentially. With many processors, defining an `xsl:key` and using the `key()` function will speed this query up (by creating an index). But a processor like Saxon-EE with a smart optimizer will build the index automatically without you asking for it explicitly.